# Performance problems modeling a MySQL to MongoDB Database with 50 million documents

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am migrating a `MySQL` `table` which has 50 million more `rows` to a MongoDB `database`. 
[JSON Document example](https://pastebin.com/1EeaL9VL)

Basically the problem I am facing is: This data will be shown on a `HTML` `table` and every column will be searchable and sortable (limiting 100 documents per pagination). I've created some testing databases on Mongo, which worked well when filtering and sorting only `indexed fields`. When there is filtering or sorting on `non-indexed fields` the `querys` runs too slow, because mongo need to scan the whole collection.

The solution I found to this problem on `mysql` was make a `subselect` limiting the filtered data, something like this:

```
select con.field1, con.field2
  from (select * from myTable order by id desc limit 40000) as con
 where con.field1 = '...' //another filters here
 order by con.field2 desc
 limit 100
```

This solution works very well on `mysql`, but I didn't found anything similar on Mongo. As I said, when I filter/sort on indexed fields, mongo querys runs very well, but I presume I can't create an index on every searchable/sortable field.

This is a query which runs fast on mongo, only filtering on indexed fields:

```
.find({
    tipo_doc: 'nfe', //indexed field
    id_empresa: 7 //indexed field
},
{
    sort: {'data_requisicao': -1}, //indexed field
    limit: 100
});
```

And this is a query which runs very slow:

```
.find({
    tipo_doc: 'nfe', //indexed field
    id_empresa: 7, //indexed field
    'transportador.xNome': 'My name' //not indexed field
},
{
    sort: {'emitente.enderEmit.UF': -1}, //not indexed field
    limit: 100
});
```

What should I do to get a better performance in this case?